# Why do we need \dots in mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

Why do we need `\dots` in mathjax? it is quicker and easier to write `...`

both of them are doing the same: `\dots` $\dots$ , `...`$...$

Comment: There are some examples in [MathJax Help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are not doing the same thing: `\dots` is a single character when rendered, but `...` is three characters when rendered. If I'm not mistaken, this could cause an automatic line break inside the "...". The spacing is also different around `\dots` (there is more space before the first dot). Moreover, `\dots` is sensitive to context, compare $x_1 + \dots + x_n$ (with `\dots`) to $x_1 + ... + x_n$ (with `...`): in the first one the dots are in the middle, while with the second one the dots are on the bottom, and you can also see that the spacing looks bad with `...`.